# youtube.googleapis.com -- how to embed video from google drive on website using youtube player

Tags: youtube-api, google-apis-explorer

inspecting the elementof a playing video on google drive gave me this source for the iframe (after decoding it):

```
"https://youtube.googleapis.com/embed/?status=ok&hl=en&allow_embed=0&ps=docs&partnerid=30&autoplay=0&docid=1aUJWCNwftLtuXZ2QRMVMIh6cNAlv8VjF&abd=0&public=true&el=preview&title=5751-09-13b Dollars.mp4&BASE_URL=https://drive.google.com/&iurl=https://drive.google.com/vt?authuser=0&id=1aUJWCNwftLtuXZ2QRMVMIh6cNAlv8VjF&s=AMedNnoAAAAAXJrugYRz2xBf8REpe1dIkuYFVoDfvRKi&cc3_module=1&reportabuseurl=https://drive.google.com/abuse?authuser=0&id=1aUJWCNwftLtuXZ2QRMVMIh6cNAlv8VjF&token=1&plid=V0QVj6yxCJMmgQ&timestamp=1553650273817&length_seconds=176&BASE_YT_URL=https://drive.google.com/&cc_load_policy=1&authuser=0&wmode=window&override_hl=1&enablecastapi=0&pipable=1&enablepostapi=1&postid=drive-viewer-video-player-object-9&origin=https://drive.google.com"
```

When I go to the link, itshows the thumbnail ofthe video, but when playing it, it says "Invalid parameters".

Looking at the GET variables in the link, it seems like, first of all, the origin and baseuri maybe prevent it from being played in another website, so IDK if that's possible to change, and also it seems like the variable:

```
token=1&plid=V0QVj6yxCJMmgQ&
```

seems to refer to some kind of API token...

Also take a look at the authuser and "s" parameters:

```
?authuser=0
&id=1aUJWCNwftLtuXZ2QRMVMIh6cNAlv8VjF
&s=AMedNnoAAAAAXJrugYRz2xBf8REpe1dIkuYFVoDfvRKi
```

I'm not sure if the id and s also refer to different kinds of API tokens that can be generated somewhere...?
SO basically, it doesn't work, so is there anything I Can plug in with server side (or client) side code somehow to embed any video from google drive (thats public) on a website using the youtube player?

BTW: I'm **not** interested in the GOogle Drive video embed link, I would like to to it with the youtube API if possible